# How to automatically update a spreadsheet from various external spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, filenames

I'm hoping someone can point a novice in the right direction. Basically I have a speadsheet  with rows of info relating to each day of the month. Currently these rows are updated manually from separate corresponding daily sheets and ideally I'd like to automate this process. One idea I've had is trying to recreate the file name for each daily sheet from with Excel but I just get REF! errors. The daily files start with dd-mm-yy and I was hoping to somehow add this date from a cell within Excel and attach it to [dd-mm-yy] worksheet file path ] to populate the current sheet with external sheet but so far not having much luck. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is a actual programing Q&A . You ask when you are struggling with something you do, not thinking about doing that has small relevance. Except for that you question is poorly written and must be reformatted. At least provide some pseudo-code for your solution.

Comment: I apologise for my poorly written irrelevant question. It has been noted sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the data tab and then "connections". Press Add and then Browse (at the bottom). Then you can select your worksheets and perhaps get a macro to update them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try that tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Say we need to extract data from a variety of workbooks.  To get the data we need to know:

1. the path to the workbook
2. the name of the workbook
3. the tab in the workbook containing the data
4. the cell in the tab containing the data

We put the necessary info into a tab as follows:

[image]

Lets assume that the information is on sheet *x*

running this macro:

```
Sub GetExternalData()

    Dim wbPath As String, WorkbookName As String
    Dim WorksheetName As String, CellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String, i As Long, N As Long

    With Sheets("x")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        wbPath = "'" & .Cells(i, 1).Value
        WorkbookName = "[" & .Cells(i, 2).Value & "]"
        WorksheetName = .Cells(i, 3).Value & "'!"
        CellRef = .Cells(i, 4).Value

        Ret = wbPath & WorkbookName & WorksheetName & Range(CellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

        .Cells(i, 5).Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

will fill column **E** with the results.
You can run the macro whenever you need to or arrange to run the macro each time the workbook is opened.